# Why does while loop not repeat in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am writing a code to print a table for the square root. But it doesn't loop. I need it to loop.

```
import math
                
def test_sqrt():
    a = 1
    def my_sqrt(a):
        while True:
            x = 1
            y = (x + a/x) / 2.0
            if y == x:
                return y

    while(a < 26):
        print('a = ' + str(a) + ' | my_sqrt(a) = ' + str(my_sqrt(a)) + ' | math.sqrt(a) = ' + str(math.sqrt(a)) + ' | diff = ' + str(my_sqrt(a) - math.sqrt(a)))
        a = a + 1
        

test_sqrt()
```

Comment: Which while loop are you referring to?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't loop? What values have you tried it with? What were the results? Edit the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
import math
            
def test_sqrt():
    a = 1
    err = 1e-6

    def my_sqrt(a):
        x=1
        while True:
            y = (x + a/x) / 2.0

            if abs(y-x)<err:
                return y
        
            x = y

    while(a < 26):
         print('a = ' + str(a) + ' | my_sqrt(a) = ' + str(my_sqrt(a)) + ' | math.sqrt(a) = ' + str(math.sqrt(a)) + ' | diff = ' + str(my_sqrt(a) - math.sqrt(a)))
        a = a + 1
    

 test_sqrt()
```

Notes:

1. The initial value of x is defined at the beginning, not each loop
2. The value of x needs to be updated each loop, if we haven't returned from the function
3. The computation is continued until it is close enough, absolute difference is less than `err`

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck in an endless loop when `a = 2` and you call `my_sqrt(2)`:

```
my_sqrt(2):
    x = 1
    y = (x + a/x) / 2.0 = 1.5
```

Since all of the variables `x`, `a` and `y` are constant in that context, the `if y == x:` condition is never used. So you stay stuck in the `while True:` loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that python is going into infinite loop when a=2. This can be checked via debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you built an infinite while-loop in your `my_sqrt(a)` function:

```
def my_sqrt(a):
    while True:
        x = 1
        y = (x + a/x) / 2.0
        if y == x:
            return y
```

With the second run you have y != x (unequal), hence there is no changing in y or x within the infinite loop, the loop will never break by reaching the `return y`.

By this, the loop:

```
while(a < 26):
    print('a = ' + str(a) + ' | my_sqrt(a) = ' + str(my_sqrt(a)) + ' | math.sqrt(a) = ' + str(math.sqrt(a)) + ' | diff = ' + str(my_sqrt(a) - math.sqrt(a)))
    a = a + 1
```

runs once an then gets stuck on the second iteration of the `my_sqrt(a)` function when a = 2.